# How can I pass a function as parameter in javascript?

Tags: javascript, function, parameters, callback

I need to create a function with a callback function, but the solutions I've found does not allow to set the function.

I'll explain:

this is the solution I've found:

```
function callbackFunction()
{
   alert("hello world");
}

function myFunction(callback)
{
   callback()
}

myFunction(callbackFunction())  /* this works */
```

this is what i need:

```
function myFunction(callback)
{
   callback()
}

myFunction(function(){alert("hello world");});  /* this doesn't work  */
```

Some ideas?

Thank you

Comment: Your code works for me. There is one error: `myFunction(callbackFunction())` should be: `myFunction(callbackFunction)`

Comment: The code works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/5KnGN/

Comment: In what way does it not work?  This is a very simple code snippit that should work as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
myFunction(callbackFunction())  /* this works */
```

No it doesn't.  At least not in the way you think it does.  This is:

1. Invoking `callbackFunction`
2. Passing the *result* of `callbackFunction` to `myFunction`

You're probably getting an error from within `myFunction` when it tries to invoke `callback` since that's not a function.  But you're ignoring that because you see the `alert()` and think it works.  The `alert()` happened before `myFunction` was invoked.

You want to pass it as a function reference, not a function invocation:

```
myFunction(callbackFunction)  /* this works */
```

This would produce the same visible result (the `alert()`) but in the expected order of operations and without the error.

---

```
myFunction(function(){alert("hello world");});  /* this doesn't work  */
```

[You sure about that?](http://jsfiddle.net/7vtt4/)  If that is indeed "not working" for you then there must be more to the problem that you're not sharing with us, because that code works as-is.

Comment: yes, you're right. I found the problem, thanks a lot!